# Neovim autoupdating file in multiple terminal buffers, not warning with swap

Tags: neovim, swap-file

I've been noticing some rather confusing behavior in my neovim setup and I'm really not even sure if it's a problem, just a feature that surprised me.

I recently noticed that the classic "This file is already open" warning message hasn't been displaying when I open a file in multiple terminals. This concerned me at first, but I just did some testing and found the following behavior:

1. Create a file (`test.md`).
2. Open the file in a terminal.
3. Open the file in a second terminal (No warning is shown)
4. Edit the file in either terminal, `:w`, and click over to the other terminal.

Result => In the other terminal the content is automatically updated to reflect the previous changes.

So far as I can tell this isn't behavior that I've explicitly set (though my `init.vim` [setup has grown rather large and spans multiple files](https://github.com/mas-4/dotfiles/tree/master/.config/nvim)). I grepped for 'swap' and the only hits I got were in Plug.

Is this new behavior in neovim or have I committed the mortal sin of installing a [plugin](https://github.com/mas-4/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/nvim/vimrc.d/plugins.vimrc) and I don't know what it does?

**Update**: I found [this explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149209/refresh-changed-content-of-file-opened-in-vim) of how to set this sort of behavior and grepping revealed nothing being set.

**Update**: Actually this is highly undesirable behavior because unsaved changes don't get updated.

Comment: I would check `:verbose set autoread?` as a first guess

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That helped. It told me the last place to set it was in vim-polyglot, I uninstalled it, and it came back. Thanks!

Comment: makes a good answer to me. Include the debugging tip^ if you will. Personally I don’t really recommend polyglot. It’s a bit too much for me and often has stuff that’s old or conflicts or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in a plugin, vim-polyglot, which was setting autoread. Disabling that plugin solved the problem.

For future readers, solving this problem was as easy as running `:verbose set autoread?` which told me the last line in all of my configurations where it was set.

Thanks to D. Ben Knoble for the tip.